# Unexpected modify of non primitive values in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

I'm working with an angular service of the type:

```
services.factory('SaveHistory', function($rootScope, $localForage){
return {
    videoAccessed: function(idPillola) {
        $localForage.getItem('trainings_user_'+$rootScope.user.id)
            .then(function(succ, err) {
                for (var item in succ) {
                    [].forEach.call(succ[item], function(el, index) {
                        el.pillole.forEach(function(el, index){
                            if (el.idPercorso == idPillola) {
                                console.log(idPillola);
                                el.tracking.completion_status = 1;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
                var newTrainings = succ;
                ...
            });         
    }
```

When the function is fired with the correct idPillola , console.log logs the correct idPillola value one single time, so it seems that the cycle works correctly. But : if the attribute in the object (object or rather 'el' in the nested forEach cycle) that i want to change is a primitive , there are no problems, if the attribute is not primitive but an another object attribute, like tracking.completion_status in this case, all elements are updated ! (Like the if control had been ignored).
It is related to Angular or Javascript itself?

Comment: Almost certainly relates to the structure of things, which you haven't shown us. Please provide a [mcve], ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: Separately: Did you *really* mean to shadow `el`? The `el` in `el.idPercorso` is not the same as the `el` in `el.pillole`. I usually try to use different variable names in nested loops, to avoid confusion. (There's also no need to declare the second argument if you're not going to use it; you're not using `index` above.)

Comment: Sure you are right , but the working code is quite long. I wanted just to know if the problem is related to any objective pattern. However thanks for advices, yes i really wanted to shadow the father 'el' beacuse i didn't need it except to get his pillole attribute, apart from that i will remove index argument, I put it just of habit.